# Comparing a String with 2d Array

Tags: c++, arrays, c-strings, turbo-c++

actually I am trying to compare a string with a 2d array.If the entered string is already present in the array the program should terminate.If the string is not present then it should be stored in the next row of array.
what this piece of code is doing is that it is not telling if the entered "cnic" has been previously entered or not. I am using Turbo C++ 3.0 compiler so please keep that in mind.

***This program actually takes cnic of user and check whether that cnic has been previously entered or not.***

**Here is my Program**

```
          cout<<"\nEnter Your CNIC?\n";
        gets(cnic);
        **for (i=0;i<=13;i++)
        {
            if (strcmp(cnic,cnic2)==0)
            {
                cout<<"This Cnic has already casted the vote";
            }
        }
        cnic2[i][j]=cnic[i];
        j++;**
```

Comment: *"I am using Turbo C++ 3.0 compiler"*.... oh no....

Comment: _@OP_ And what's your question please?

Comment: Damn, that compiler is older than me...

Comment: It is a waste to learn the archaic version of C++ supported by Turbo C++.

Comment: @crashmstr I'm wondering what the indian rocket scientists use :( ...

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ i want to compare the string with that array and if the string is already present then program shuld give error and if it is not present then that string should store in the array,

Comment: @RajaHaseeb And in which way your code doesn't do this correctly?

Comment: actually it is a university project that has to be submitted by tommorow and they have only allowed the turbo C++.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ actually it is neither comparing the string cnic[13] with cnic2[13][100] nor storing it. what i want is that if cnic(e.g "1234567890123") is already present in cnic2 it should give some error and if it is not present then the cnic should store in cnic2.

Comment: @RajaHaseeb Effectively you compare a `char*` pointer with a `char**` pointer. you should use something like `cnic2[x]` to compare the `char*` contents.

Comment: Believe it or not depending on what you are working you might face some pretty ancient code that you have bust your ass to maintain (this is more of an answer to some of the comments above). That said I don't know how things were in Turbo C++ 3.0 but from what I'm seeing it's more of C code thing here when it comes to strings. strcmp is definitely the way to go. You simple have to traverse line-wise your array and compare it with your string. I suggest using pointers here btw.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ 
actually i haven't studied pointers yet and this has to be submitted by tomorrow so if you could please give me some example.

Comment: @rbaleksandar atually i haven't studied pointers yet. :'(

Comment: @RajaHaseeb _"atually i haven't studied pointers yet"_ But you're using them all over in your code? (see declaration of [`strcmp()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strcmp))

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ i had to skip some classes to prepare for some exams, i actually took some help online, please if you could revise the code specially the for within asterisks ?

Comment: @iharob if you could help me with this please

Comment: @RajaHaseeb - You have `goto` in your code.  Get rid of it.  If the university is worth anything, you would get points deducted for that `goto` in your code.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie surely i will but for now i am not able to compare the strings (trying for like 10hours or so) and i have to submit that tommorow :'(

Comment: @RajaHaseeb _"and i have to submit that tommorow"_ Restating that isn't an excuse for anything. It's your fault, and you deserve a **F**. (hopefully you're not heading for rocket science, that'll make our skies even more insecure as they already are)

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ but i still managed to figure out where i was making mistakes, thanks to Serge,and well for someone who has started c++ 2 months ago it is a rocket science. 
Wasn't making an excuse, just wanted someone "experienced" to tell me where i was making mistake, and i did it, and i don't care about grades, as long as i have done something with my full interest and heart i don;t care ;) thank you and peace :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used Turbo C (even not ++) but it was long long time ago ... More seriously, I assume :

- `cnic` is a char array of size 13 (12 + terminating null)
- `cnic2` should be a 2D array of 100 char arrays of size 13 (it is not what is written in your code)
- you want to see if `cnic` C-string is already in `cnic2`, if it is you reject it, if not you add it.
- `j` is the index of next element in `cnic2`, and should be explicitely set to 0 before main loop.

Declaration :

```
char cnic2[100][13];
int found; /* should be bool found but unsure if Turbo C++ knows about that */
```

(you code was declaring a array of 13 C-Ctring of size 100)

Test loop (including code reviewed and tested by OP) :

```
/* should control size of nic before that processing - I ASSUME IT HAS BEEN DONE */
found = 0;  /* should be found = false; and later use false and true instead of 0 and 1 */
for(i=0; i<j; i++) {
    if (0 == strcmp(cnic, cnic2[i]) {
        found = 1;
        break;
    }
}
if (found) {
    cout<<"This Cnic has already casted the vote";
    continue;
}
if (j == 99) {
    count << "Too much Cnic already";
    break;  
}
strcpy(cnic2[j++], cnic);


/* Revised and Working Code

found = 0;  /* should be found = false; and later use false and true instead of 0 and 1 */

for(i=0; i<j; i++) {

    if (0 == strcmp(cnic, cnic2[i]))
    {
        found = 1;  
        break;
    }

}
if (found) {
    cout<<"This Cnic has already casted the vote";
    continue;  
}
if (j == 99) {
    cout << "Too much Cnic already";
    break;   
}
strcpy(cnic2[j++], cnic);
```

Comment: thank you for the reply, by cnic[100][13] i meant 13 coloumns and 100 rows, btw limme check.

Comment: thank you, i made few changes in the code and now it is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

Concentrating on the code you marked with `**`.  The mistakes are numbered below:

```
for (i=0;i<=13;i++) // (1)
{
    if (strcmp(cnic,cnic2)==0)  // (2)
    {
        cout<<"This Cnic has already casted the vote";
    }
}
cnic2[i][j]=cnic[i]; // (3)
```

For mistake `(1)`, you are looping too many times.  You want to loop from 0 to 12, or use `< 13`, not `<= 13`.

For mistake `(2)`, the second argument to `strcmp()` is wrong.  You want to compare the string starting at `cnic2[j]`.

For mistake `(3)`, you are accessing an element out-of-bounds of both arrays, since `i` will be 13.

I won't fix these for you, since your code does much more.  My answer pointed out was is obviously wrong.

Comment: thank you for your reply, i have edited my code but when i reenter the cnic that i had written earlier it doesn't reject it.